# VS or WIX MSI installer - show serial number from first install

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, wix, windows-installer

I'd like to show the serial number in the CustomerInfo form (which was captured from the first install and installed in the registry) within the second, third, etc installs when the upgrade is simply a minor version change (or patch).  Is this something that can be done within VS deployment project and/or WIX via a custom action (I have a C++ method to fetch the SerialNumber from the registry), MSI config (thru editing a table(s) via say Orca), or otherwise
Regards
Travis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I always do PerMachine installs and don't bother to show the customer information dialog.  If an application wants to have licensing it's best to do it in the application on first run.

If you really want to do it in the MSI, you've got a lot of work ahead of you.  MSI doesn't persist properties across transactions so you'll have to do it yourself.  See:

[The WiX toolset's "Remember Property" pattern](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern/)

I have an open source project called [IsWiX](http://iswix.codeplex.com). It includes a Visual Studio project template that creates an installer project framework.  Part of that framework shows how to insert a custom dialog and then authors a component to handle the remember property for the control on that dialog.  You can find the source [here](http://iswix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#main/Source/Application/IsWiXAddIn/MSISolutionTemplate/SetupProjectTemplate/UI-CustomDialog.wxs).

Comment: Many thanks for the quick response Chris - the pattern described in the article looks good - I'll give this a try

Comment: Hi Chris - I implemented the pattern in the article and it works well - the only question I have is it talks about a user level install Vs machine level - i.e. persisting the serial number to HKCU Vs HKLM.  The problem is I won't know this ahead of time as it is an option within the install process - do I need two different sections within my WIX file to accommodate : "Package InstallScope='perUser'" and "Package InstallScope='perMachine'" with corresponding registry locations (HKCU and HKLM resp.)

Comment: Do you really, really need to support a per-user installation?  That pattern is very hard to service in an enterprise environment and is best for when you have "viral" apps that spread word of mouth and are installed  by users without admin rights.  In that situation all resources have to go places they have permission.  Typically this means HKCU instead of HKLM.  In all of my years and hundreds of installers written I've never had a valid business case for one.  I just remove the option and build the MSI to be perMachine.

Comment: I'm fairly new to releasing software to external companies so I wasn't sure whether there was an expectation out there to cater for both.  If it's difficult to implement both simultaneously, as you suggest, I'll go with perMachine only (I can always create two installers if there's an appetite for both options).  Many thanks for your help on this - installers for externals are a bit of a minefield

Answer (score 2):

I'll skip the WiX part that Chris covered.

To do this in a VS project you're supposed to use the Customer Information dialog, added from the list of extra canned dialogs, and use the SerialNumberTemplate stuff. That sets the ProductID property which is the way you're supposed to do serial numbers. So then you could create a registry item in the Visual Studio IDE that has the value [ProductID] to save it somewhere personal.  The "official" way to get hold of it for an installed product is MsiGetProductInfo() or equivalent passing the ProductCode and asking for "ProductID" as documented here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370130(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

To summarize, if the package uses the official PIDKEY /ProductID mechanism (like VS and maybe WiX) you don't need to save it yourself and you can get it via MsiGetProductInfo() or a scipt/managed code equivalent.

If you want to show that previous SerialNumber in a VS setup in the standard customer information form on an upgrade, I don't believe you can do that. There's no mechanism for getting into those forms. If you save the SerialNumber privately, you could try a registry search for your saved serialnumber and store it in the PIDKEY property to see if it shows up there, that might work because the PIDKEY property is the source for that value.